# Choose results by date filter PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin

I have one page (members.php) that post date to another page (results.php). Using the below code, i can successfully get the "to" and "from" variables from the members page.

```
<?php echo $_POST["to"]; ?>
<?php echo $_POST["from"]; ?>
```

My problem now is, how can i create a query (in results.php) in order to show filter results only for the dates that are specified at the above variables? Do i need to create an sql connection and sql query too?

Comment: do you want to display results between the two dates

Comment: Yes exactly, but as i understand i have to create a whole new SQL connection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If dates are in `YYYY-mm-dd` format then you can use it as below otherwise you need to change the format.**

You can do as below :

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
   die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

//$from_date = $_POST['from_date'];
//$to_date = $_POST['to_date'];

$from_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('06/10/2015'));
$to_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('06/16/2015'));//$_POST['to_date'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE from_date >= '".$from_date."' AND to_date <= '".$to_date."'";
// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Hello, but how do i set up the connection to MySQL? Can you please write the complete format?

Comment: Thank you but i got this "Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: Its a deprecated warning. You can suppress it by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);` in the top.

Comment: Thank you! Now i got no error at all, but the results doesn't appear. Do i have to create an output ?

Comment: Have you created database with table and some dummy data?

Comment: yes of course! The database has dummy data inside. When i choose the dates i get no error, but also i get no results at all. Don't i have somehow to create an output code?

Comment: This is to print the result. `print_r($row);`. Can you `echo $query;` and let me know the output?

Comment: This is the output : SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE date >= '06/10/2015' AND date <= '06/10/2015'.  (My table name is t1. Also i have one column to save dates) NOTE: On MySQL the date is timestamp and this is the format: 2015-06-10 12:00:00

Comment: @Leonidas : The date is not in `YYYY-mm-dd`. You need to change that in code.

Comment: You are amazing!! Thank you so much!! Please send me an e-mail at info[at]dataone.gr with your contact details. I have a job offer for you ( i am serious - no kidding)

Comment: Yes it worked! Please send me your contact details. We have a small PHP & MySQL project to complete, and you are the suitable person to join our team!!

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to database and compare this two dates:

```
$dateOne = $_POST["from"];
$dateTwo = $_POST["to"];
```

If bigger date is 0, then you should always make it the highest date possible to successfully query Data:

```
if(empty($dateTwo))
{
    $dateTwo =  date("31-12-Y");
    //If $dateTwo is null, than it will be 31/12/2015 otherwise query will now work well 
}
```

Then you should write sql query like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` where `dateOne` > '$dateOne' and `dateTwo` < '$dateTwo'";
```

In this case if user wants all dates bigger than dateOne but doesn't check dateTwo, this query will return all data bigger than dateOne and lower than highest date available in current year (In our case it's 31/21/2015).

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessarily creating a new sql connection but just a new query (proposed you have already connected to the database). In my opinion, if you want to display the results between the two dates.

I am not checking for existing or empty values since the dates have been already given.

So:

```
<?php $start_date = $_POST["from"];
      $end_date   = $_POST["to"]; 

    //sql will be 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `the_date_column` BETWEEN {$start_date} AND {$end_date}";
?>
```

Please but doing this use mysqli or PDO connection layer and also try to escape the variables to prevent sql injection or better off, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE build_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.